# Why does the mohel say the brocha at the bris?

Tags: blessing, torah-reading, brit-milah, shlichus-agency

Optimally, a father should circumcise his own sons.  Optimally, an aliyah should read the Torah when called up.  When we are called up for an aliyah, we say the brocha and the baal koreh reads for us.  At a bris, though, the mohel says the brocha.  Why doesn't the father say the brocha at the bris, and then the mohel performs the bris for him?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be asked the other way around( i.e.: If the performer of the act, and not the one in who's name it is done, is to say the _Berakhah_ , like the _Mohel_ who says the _Berakhah_ before performing the _Milah_ , why does the _Oleh la-Torah_ say the _Berakhah_ , when it is the _Ba'al Qore'_ that performs the _Qeri'at ha-Torah_ for him)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I said the bracha at my son's bris.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Did you say "_la-Mul et ha-Ben_"( or "_al ha-Milah_"), which is the _Berakhah_ the performer of the _Milah_ says, or "_le-Hakhniso bi-Bhrito shel Avraham Avinu_", which the father says?

Comment: @TamirEvan ah.  I said "*shel Avraham Avinu*".  Perhaps that should be added to the question.

Comment: yoel, off the top of my head some other brachot that the shliach says include hafrashat terumot, kiddushin, pidyon haben, biur chametz and mezuzah.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is really the other way around. Generally speaking it's the person who does the mitzva action that says the bracha (Rambam [Brachot 11:10](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=2&hilchos=10&perek=11&halocha=10&hilite=)). In the case of an aliyah, you are right that in most congregations an appointed reader is designated to read each persons portion out loud and with proper cantillation; however Shulchan Aruch (OC 141:2) rules that the one receiving the aliyah must read along with the leader in an undertone so that his blessings should not be in vain. We see that even in the case of an aliyah the bracha is said by the performer of the mitzva action itself.

Comment: You should also see a piece by R Chaim Soloveitchik in the stencils about the bracha on mezuzah when putting it up on someone else's house.

Comment: Can you source your second sentence (w.r.t. a _mitzva_ done by another)?

Comment: Unless the 'Oleh is illiterate. Then it is said by someone other than the performer of the Mitzvah.

Comment: @SethJ You assume an illiterate person can get an aliyah (not just out of concerns such as kavod habriyot).

Comment: @DoubleAA, they do all the time.

Comment: @SethJ מי שאינו יודע לקרות צריך למחות בידו שלא יעלה לספר תורה ואם צריכים לזה שאינו יודע לקרות לפי שהוא כהן או לוי ואין שם אחר זולתו אם כשיקרא לו שליח ציבור מלה במלה יודע לאומרה ולקרותה מן הכתב יכול לעלות ואם לאו לא יעלה: OC 139:2

Comment: @DoubleAA, they still go up. All. The. Time.

Comment: @SethJ I know, I'm just trying to emphasize the weight of evidence against the practice. Have a look at Maseit Binyamin 62 for more. As regards our local issue you have to say something like the Oleh blesses on his Shomea KeOneh because otherwise, in the words of the Rosh "שיברך הוא על מה שהחזן קורא והוא לא יקרא כלל לא יתכן".

Comment: @SethJ Teshuvot Hagaonim # 756 is about this. The ruling there is that it is absolutely forbidden for someone illiterate to get an aliyah and make a beracha. "כי איך יברך זה ויקרא זה"